# Regular expression to split a string in Julia

Tags: regex, julia

I have strings that I need to split them each time I see one of "^" or "+" character. Specifically, I need to to it in julia but I guess, Regex is independent from the PL I work. As an example, if my string is `"this^DB+Verb+Pos^DB+Noun+Inf2+A3sg+Pnon+Nom"` I want to get :

```
["this","DB","Verb","Pos","DB" ,"Noun","Inf2","A3sg","Pnon","Nom"]
```

What should be the regex to do that ?

Comment: does it have to be a regEx? You could easily use a split function instead.

Comment: Not accually have to be regEx but I though if I use split, I need to call it twice: One for the whole string with "+" seperator and than for each substring call another split  function with "^" seperator?  @shockawave123

Comment: try something like `a = "this^DB+Verb+Pos^DB+Noun+Inf2+A3sg+Pnon+Nom" ` then `split(a,"^+")`

Comment: Thanks for all solutions, they work in demo as you show but  I couldn't find a way to use them in julia yet. Working on it.

Comment: @shockawave123 To make `split` do the job, you need to replace `"^+"` with a collection of characters i.e `split(a,['^','+'])`. And @zwlayer, this would be faster than regex (timed as 2x faster on my machine)

Comment: Ahhh thanks. Good to know. @DanGetz

Comment: The fastest I found (just slightly faster than `split(a, ['^', '+'])`) is `split(a, ('^', '+'))`.

Comment: Or just split with any non-word char and `_`, use `split(whole_string ,r"[\\W_]")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this wiki https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Strings_and_characters it's possible to use RegEx in Julia's `split()` function.

The RegEx you need is `[+^]`.

```
whole_string="this^DB+Verb+Pos^DB+Noun+Inf2+A3sg+Pnon+Nom"
split(whole_string ,r"[+^]")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for:

```
[^^+]+
```

"One or more characters that are not a `^` or a `+`". [Live demo.](https://regex101.com/r/id8Sko/1)

Alternatively:

```
\b[[:alnum:]]+\b
```

"One or more alphanumeric characters enclosed by a word boundary." [Live demo.](https://regex101.com/r/id8Sko/3)

Comment: I think the second regEx fails in the demo. Only shows 2 matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple

```
([^(\^|\+)]+)
```

would do, check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uPdaB2/1)